# Ошибка работы телеграмм бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Простой бот: на выбор 2 варианта: сделать чёрно-белым или увеличить контрастность. После запуска программы и выбора варианта, например сделать чёрно-белым, всё работает, но если после этого выбрать увеличить контрастность, или просто прислать изображение, то всё равно делает изображение чёрно-белым, с увеличением контрастности ситуация точно такая же. (как должно работать: в кнопках выбирают вариант, после этого присылают фото и его обрабатывается, после этого заново делается выбор)

````
import telebot
from telebot import types
import os
from valuesforimagebot import bottokenforimagebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot(bottokenforimagebot)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_command(message):
   # Приветственное сообщение
   response = "Привет! Я могу работать с изображениями! для помощи писать в лс @Leokudtg"
   # Отправка приветственного сообщения с меню
   bot.send_message(message.chat.id, response)
   # Создаем разметку клавиатуры
   markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
   item1 = types.KeyboardButton('Сделать чёрно-белым')
   item2 = types.KeyboardButton('Увеличить контрастность')
   markup.add(item1, item2)

   # Отправляем сообщение с кнопками
   bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите опцию', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def handle_message(message):
   if message.text == 'Сделать чёрно-белым':
       bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "отправьте ваше фото, чтобы сделать его чёрно-белым")
       @bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
       def convert_to_gray(message):
           # Получаем файл из сообщения
           file_info = bot.get_file(message.photo[-1].file_id)
           downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
           # Сохраняем файл
           with open("image1.jpg", 'wb') as new_file:
               new_file.write(downloaded_file)
               # Открываем и конвертируем изображение в оттенки серого
           image1 = Image.open("image1.jpg").convert('L')
           # Сохраняем конвертированное изображение
           image1.save("gray_image.jpg")
           # Отправляем конвертированное изображение
           with open("gray_image.jpg", 'rb') as photo1:
               bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1)
           os.remove('gray_image.jpg')
           os.remove('image1.jpg')
   elif message.text == "Увеличить контрастность":
       bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "отправьте ваше фото, чтобы сделать его более контрастным")
       @bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
       def kontrastnoct (message):
           # Получаем файл из сообщения
           file_info = bot.get_file(message.photo[-1].file_id)
           downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
           # Сохраняем файл
           with open("image2.jpg", 'wb') as new_file:
               new_file.write(downloaded_file)
               # Открываем и конвертируем изображение в оттенки серого
           image2 = Image.open("image2.jpg").filter(ImageFilter.EDGE_ENHANCE_MORE)

           # Сохраняем конвертированное изображение
           image2.save("better_image.jpg")

           # Отправляем конвертированное изображение
           with open("better_image.jpg", 'rb') as photo2:
               bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo2)
           os.remove("better_image.jpg")
           os.remove('image2.jpg')
if __name__ == '__main__':
   bot.polling()```
````

Comment: Вам нужно использовать `register_next_step_handler` т.к. при создании новых handler-ров с одинаковыми фильтрами возникают конфликты.

Comment: ну и заворачивание хэндлеров в другие хэндлеры - вещь непредсказуемая